# what is the difference in Teradata (ANSI SQL) and Oracle/My SQL regarding sum(x) over (partition by y order by y)?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

Original Table X as :

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | GRP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2017-10-15 | 2018-10-21 | 1 |
| 001 | 2017-10-15 | 2019-10-21 | 0 |
| 001 | 2020-05-18 | 2021-05-03 | 1 |

````
select ID, start_date, end_date,
sum(grp) over(partition by ID order by start_date, end_date) as island
from X
```


In Teradata the result is:


| ID       | START_DATE   | END_DATE | island |
| -------- | ------------ | -------- |------- |
| 001      | 2017-10-15   |2018-10-21|  2     |
| 001      | 2017-10-15   |2019-10-21|  2     |
| 001      | 2020-05-18   |2021-05-03|  2     |


In Oracle and MySQL the results are: 
| ID       | START_DATE   | END_DATE | island |
| -------- | ------------ | -------- |------- |
| 001      | 2017-10-15   |2018-10-21|  1     |
| 001      | 2017-10-15   |2019-10-21|  1     |
| 001      | 2020-05-18   |2021-05-03|  2     |

Any suggestions to fix the Teradata result? Many thanks !!
````

Comment: The problem is in Teradata the order by function is not properly executed as in other SQL

Comment: Are you looking for a running sum?  We may be getting into semantics here, but I would say the Teradata result is exactly what you asked it to do.  Try this:  `sum(grp) over(partition by ID order by start_date, end_date  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as island`

Comment: Teradate defauls to `rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following` while Standard SQL uses a default `RANGE unbounded preceding` when ORDER BY is used.

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem gets solved!